# Is my conjecture true? : Every primorial is a superior highly regular number, and every superior highly regular number is a primorial.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, prime-factorization, primorial

I have invented two sets of positive integers: highly regular numbers and superior highly regular numbers.

A positive integer $m \leq n$ is a regular of the positive integer $n$ if all prime numbers that divide $m$ also divide $n$.

So for example:

- 4 has 3 regulars: 1, 2, 4.
- 6 has 5 regulars: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6.
- 8 has 4 regulars: 1, 2, 4, 8.
- 9 has 3 regulars: 1, 3, 9.
- 10 has 6 regulars: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10.
- 12 has 8 regulars: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12.
- A prime number has 2 regulars: 1 and itself.

$r(n)$ denotes the function which counts the quantity of regulars of the positive integer $n$.

A highly regular number is a positive integer $n$ for which $r(n) > r(q)$ for all positive integer $q < n$.

So a highly regular number is a positive integer with more regulars than any smaller positive integer.

I’ve found that the first highly regular numbers up to 210 are: 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 18, 24, 30, 42, 60, 84, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210.

A superior highly regular number is a positive integer $n$ for which there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that:
$$\frac{r(n)}{n^\epsilon} \geq \frac{r(k)}{k^\epsilon}$$
for all positive integers $k > 1$.

I've found that the first superior highly regular numbers up to 210 are: 2, 6, 30, 210.

Consequently, I’ve made a conjecture: Every primorial is a superior highly regular number, and every superior highly regular number is a primorial.

Could someone prove that my conjecture is true?

Comment: What are the values for $\epsilon$ that fit $2,6,30,210?$

Comment: Oh, well. One thing you do not appear to have done is prove that your $r(n)/n^\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$ This was straightforward for Ramanujan, but your function is not number-theoretic multiplicative.

Comment: - For 2: 1.000 to 0.834
- For 6: 0.834 to 0.796
- For 30: 0.796 to 0.683
- For 210: 0.683 to 0.595
- For 2310: 0.595 to 0.550
- For 30030: 0.550 to 0.504
- For 510510: 0.504 to 0.481
- For 9699690: 0.481 to 0.455
- For 223092870: 0.455 to 0.427
- For 6469693230: 0.426 to 0.416
- For 200560490130: 0.416 to 0.397
- For 7420738134810: 0.397 to 0.386
- For 304250263527210: 0.386 to 0.379
  
The values I’ve found may be false if my conjecture is false and there exist superior highly regular numbers which are not primorials.

Comment: The regulars of $n$ are the factors of $n$ plus the cases where a prime power factor can have the power increased by $1$ and still stay less than $n$.  So for $120=2^3\cdot3 \cdot 5$ the regulars have all the factors plus $16,9,25$.  For a number with lots of prime factors, it will be the number of factors plus the number of primes that divide it.  I am not sure it brings much to the table beyond what the divisor count does.

Answer (score 1):

There is a strong tendency for numbers that just increase the count of "regulars" to resemble primorials.

---

```
The output supports some simple ideas, some of which might be provable. 
The primorial numbers, marked with a P, give both a large count "c"
and a small log ratio log n / log c.  Several numbers before a primorial
 are in arithmetic progression, the common difference being the previous
 primorial.  The next few numbers after a primorial are also squarefree; 
there is a relatively large gap in n immediately following a primorial.
Indeed, the next n after a primorial seems to be the result of replacing
 the final prime by its successor, so the jump in magnitude of n is 
entirely dependent on the size of the "prime gap."  And, this next n is,
accordingly, rather larger than the primorial plus the previous primorial. 


log(n)/log(c)   n        c           n = factored
-----           1        1           1 = 1
1               2 P      2           2 = 2
1.2618          4        3           4 = 2^2
1.1132          6 P      5           6 = 2 * 3
1.2850         10        6          10 = 2 * 5
1.1949         12        8          12 = 2^2 * 3
1.2552         18       10          18 = 2 * 3^2
1.3253         24       11          24 = 2^3 * 3
1.1767         30 P     18          30 = 2 * 3 * 5
1.2693         42       19          42 = 2 * 3 * 7
1.2566         60       26          60 = 2^2 * 3 * 5
1.3296         84       28          84 = 2^2 * 3 * 7
1.2983         90       32          90 = 2 * 3^2 * 5
1.3359        120       36         120 = 2^3 * 3 * 5
1.3492        150       41         150 = 2 * 3 * 5^2
1.3722        180       44         180 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5
1.2672        210 P     68         210 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7
1.3350        330       77         330 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 11
1.3615        390       80         390 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 13
1.3233        420       96         420 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7
1.3584        630      115         630 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7
1.3811        840      131         840 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7
1.3978       1050      145        1050 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7
1.4136       1260      156        1260 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7
1.4266       1470      166        1470 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2
1.4395       1680      174        1680 = 2^4 * 3 * 5 * 7
1.4481       1890      183        1890 = 2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7
1.4550       2100      192        2100 = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7
1.3719       2310 P    283        2310 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.3912       2730      295        2730 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 13
1.4236       3570      313        3570 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 17
1.4358       3990      322        3990 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 19
1.4192       4620      382        4620 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.4392       5460      395        5460 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 13
1.4465       6930      452        6930 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.4680       8190      463        8190 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 13
1.4669       9240      505        9240 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.4872      10920      519       10920 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 13
1.4820      11550      551       11550 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11
1.5017      13650      567       13650 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 13
1.4935      13860      593       13860 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.5038      16170      629       16170 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11
1.5132      18480      660       18480 = 2^4 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.5206      20790      691       20790 = 2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.5281      23100      717       23100 = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11
1.5343      25410      743       25410 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11^2
1.5403      27720      766       27720 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11
1.4609      30030 P   1161       30030 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.4878      39270     1224       39270 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 17
1.4985      43890     1253       43890 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 19
1.5056      46410     1257       46410 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 13 * 17
1.5165      51870     1285       51870 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 13 * 19
1.5165      53130     1306       53130 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 23
1.5010      60060     1526       60060 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5281      78540     1597       78540 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 17
1.5388      87780     1631       87780 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 19
1.5244      90090     1779       90090 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5514     117810     1856      117810 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 17
1.5411     120120     1977      120120 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5539     150150     2144      150150 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5639     180180     2294      180180 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5729     210210     2420      210210 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13
1.5804     240240     2538      240240 = 2^4 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5871     270270     2645      270270 = 2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5931     300300     2743      300300 = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5984     330330     2836      330330 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11^2 * 13
1.6034     360360     2921      360360 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.6080     390390     3001      390390 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13^2
1.6120     420420     3080      420420 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13
1.6159     450450     3153      450450 = 2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.6195     480480     3223      480480 = 2^5 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13
1.5489     510510 P   4843      510510 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.5584     570570     4939      570570 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.5742     690690     5119      690690 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 23
1.5826     746130     5138      746130 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 17 * 19
1.5926     870870     5364      870870 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 29
1.5979     930930     5436      930930 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 31
1.5837    1021020     6225     1021020 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.5932    1141140     6337     1141140 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6091    1381380     6546     1381380 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 23
1.6175    1492260     6560     1492260 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 17 * 19
1.6040    1531530     7178     1531530 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6135    1711710     7299     1711710 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6183    2042040     7928     2042040 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6278    2282280     8055     2282280 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6293    2552550     8553     2552550 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6389    2852850     8685     2852850 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6383    3063060     9099     3063060 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6478    3423420     9236     3423420 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6459    3573570     9580     3573570 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6554    3993990     9719     3993990 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6525    4084080    10010     4084080 = 2^4 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6620    4564560    10155     4564560 = 2^4 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
1.6582    4594590    10414     4594590 = 2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6634    5105100    10777     5105100 = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6681    5615610    11120     5615610 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11^2 * 13 * 17
1.6723    6126120    11441     6126120 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6762    6636630    11740     6636630 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13^2 * 17
1.6798    7147140    12027     7147140 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6832    7657650    12293     7657650 = 2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6864    8168160    12549     8168160 = 2^5 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6893    8678670    12799     8678670 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17^2
1.6920    9189180    13037     9189180 = 2^2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17
1.6245    9699690 P  19985     9699690 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19  
1.6387   11741730    20605    11741730 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 23
1.6474   13123110    20929    13123110 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19 * 23
1.6554   14804790    21453    14804790 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 29
1.6600   15825810    21713    15825810 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 31
1.6641   16546530    21769    16546530 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19 * 29
1.6688   17687670    22028    17687670 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19 * 31
1.6722   18888870    22443    18888870 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 37
1.6552   19399380    25289    19399380 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.6694   23483460    26005    23483460 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 23
1.6781   26246220    26370    26246220 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19 * 23
1.6730   29099070    28924    29099070 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.6872   35225190    29701    35225190 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 23
1.6856   38798760    31776    38798760 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.6998   46966920    32594    46966920 = 2^3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 23
1.6953   48498450    34150    48498450 = 2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7032   58198140    36204    58198140 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7099   67897830    38028    67897830 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7157   77597520    39660    77597520 = 2^4 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7208   87297210    41161    87297210 = 2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7254   96996900    42543    96996900 = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7295  106696590    43827   106696590 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7333  116396280    45029   116396280 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7367  126095970    46156   126095970 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13^2 * 17 * 19
1.7399  135795660    47233   135795660 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7429  145495350    48240   145495350 = 2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7457  155195040    49202   155195040 = 2^5 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7483  164894730    50130   164894730 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17^2 * 19
1.7507  174594420    51014   174594420 = 2^2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7530  184294110    51861   184294110 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19^2
1.7552  193993800    52680   193993800 = 2^3 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7573  203693490    53468   203693490 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.7593  213393180    54226   213393180 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19
1.6970  223092870 P  83074   223092870 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23
1.7121  281291010    86054   281291010 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 29
1.7164  300690390    86978   300690390 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 31
log(n)/log(c)  n       c           n   =   factored
```

---

```
set<int> PrimeFac(int i)
{
  set<int> boo;

  int p = 2;
  int temp = i;
  if (temp < 0 )
  {
    temp *= -1;
  }

  if ( temp > 1)
  {

    while( temp > 1 && p * p <= temp)
    {
      if (temp % p == 0)
      {

        boo.insert(p);

        temp /= p;

        while (temp % p == 0)
        {
          temp /= p;

        } // while p is fac

      }  // if p is factor
      ++p;
    } // while p

    if (temp > 1 )  boo.insert(temp);
  } // temp > 1
  return boo;
} // end of  PrimeFac



set<int> Radical_Divides_Radical(int n)
{
   set<int> boo;
   boo.insert(1);
   if (n <= 1) return boo;
   else
   {
     set<int> fax;
     fax = PrimeFac(n);
     set<int>::iterator iter;

     for(iter = fax.begin() ;  iter != fax.end(); ++iter)
     {
        set<int> more;
       int p = *iter;
       int power = 1;
    set<int>::iterator iter2;
       while ( power <= n / p)
       {
         power *= p;

          for(iter2 = boo.begin() ;  iter2 != boo.end(); ++iter2)
          {
            int u = *iter2;
            if ( u <= n / power ) more.insert( power * u);
          } // iter 2
       } // while
        for(iter2 = more.begin() ;  iter2 != more.end(); ++iter2)
          {
            int u = *iter2;
            if ( u <= n ) boo.insert(  u);
          } // iter 2
     } // iter
     return boo;
   } // else   n >= 2

} // end of Radical_Divides_Radical
```

---

Comment: What language did you use for this? I know some number libraries that could really speed this up (numbers here are quite small)

Comment: @qwr, it's just C++, in this case ordinary integers, so it cannot go more than $2^{31}.$ The summary is that i do not see how the analogy with Ramanujan's method is going to work, too many aspects are not proved.

Comment: @qwr, edited in the two main routines used. this is C++ with STL.