# Is every primorial number squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, primorial

> Is every primorial number ( a number of the form $p$#$\pm 1$ ) squarefree ?

According to my calculation, there is no prime $q\le 270,000$, such that
$q^2$ can be a divisor of $p$#$-1$ or $p$#$+1$. The PARI/GP program is as
follows

```
? p=1;gef=0;while(gef==0,p=nextprime(p+1);if(Mod(p,10^4)==1,print(p));q=p^2;n=1;
forprime(s=1,p,n=n*s;n=component(Mod(n,q),2);if(Mod(n^2-1,q)==0,gef=1;print(s,"
 ",q))))
70001
90001
150001
160001
180001
270001
```

Have I programed correctly ?

Considering that no small squares can divide a primorial number, I strongly
conjecture that they are all squarefree. But can it be proven ?

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805817/is-my-conjecture-true-every-primorial-is-a-superior-highly-regular-number-an), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220162/are-euclid-numbers-squarefree). So they should be squarefree, but there is no prove, I think.

Comment: Numbers of this form are called [Euclid numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number).  The wiki page has a book reference that states that your question remains open.